# Create video from a set if images in .Net 6

Tags: image, video, .net-6.0, webapi

I have a set of images in a folder and would like to create a video from all of those images.

I have tried to get some from google, however they are not supporting .Net 6.

If there is any inbuilt feature available in .net core 6 please let us know or if there are any 3rd party software(s) available, please let us know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can this library

```
dotnet add package FFmpeg.NET --version 6.0.2
```

Create a video from a set of images

```
// Set the input and output file paths
string inputPath = "C:\\images\\";
string outputPath = "C:\\video.mp4";
// Create a new FFmpeg instance
FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg();
// Set the input and output arguments
string inputArguments = $"-pattern_type glob -i '{inputPath}*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -r 30";
string outputArguments = outputPath;

// Execute the FFmpeg command to create the video
ffmpeg.Execute(inputArguments, outputArguments);
```